# PHP error method doesn't exist in the Child class, method_exists($child, $method) passes

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with Laravel 5.1 here.
I have created two classes, one extending the other:

```
abstract class ActivityTimeline extends Model
```

Which has:

```
$this->fields = [
   'owner_id',
   'contact_name',
   'mailing_label',
   'source_id',
   'source_raw',
   'initial_referer_raw',
   'primary_person',
   'connections',
];
foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
    if (method_exists($this, $field)) {
        dd('the method exists', $this, $field);
        $timelineActivity[$field] = $this->{$field}();
    }
}
```

And

```
class ContactActivity extends ActivityTimeline {
```

Which has:

```
public function primary_person()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryPerson($this->record);
}
```

The "dd('the method exists', $this, $field);" returns the following:

> "the method exists"
>
> ContactActivity {#963 ▶}
>
> "primary_person"

However when this if statement passes, and I attempt to call the method that I just checked the existence of, I get:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2123:
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::primary_person()

So it seems that I'm not working with a ContactActivity object here, even though the dd shows that I am.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here to get the wrong object?

Comment: A thought that I just had.  This is probably happening because at this point in the game, I have not yet done a save() on my ContactActivity object?  If so, what would be the proper way to access this method?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you call a child method from the parent class.
Try to add

```
abstract function primary_person();
```

On ActivityTimeline class